# Issue with displaying Error message in a page having two forms

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I am developing one JSF page, in that i am having two forms.  And I am using rich:messages in both the forms.

Suppose, in the first form, if I don't enter any required fields and I click Save, then error messages are displaying **twice** in the page(as i am using **rich:messages** in two forms).

Is there any way so that error messages display with respect to the form?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using RichFaces 3.3.3.Final you can do it like so:

```
<a4j:form id="tmpfrm1">
    <rich:messages />
    <h:inputText value="#{mybean.intmp1}" required="true"/>
    <a4j:commandButton value="save" action="#{mybean.test1}" reRender="tmpfrm1" limitToList="true" />
</a4j:form>

<a4j:form id="tmpfrm2">
    <rich:messages />
    <h:inputText value="#{mybean.intmp2}" required="true"/>
    <a4j:commandButton value="save" action="#{mybean.test2}" reRender="tmpfrm2" limitToList="true" />
</a4j:form>
```

If you are uisng RichFaces 4 you need to replace the limitToList with limitRender and the reRender with render